# Multiple CXF servers binding gets overridden by the first server

Tags: spring, osgi, cxf

I have multiple `WAR`s that all use a `CXFServlet` to handle all requests and `Spring` configuration.

All of them share a similar `web.xml` (yes, it's on `OSGi` as well):

```
<web-app id="app1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

All of them share a common `Spring` config as well (the `common-rest.xml`):

```
<beans>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <!-- For brevity I left out jaxRSProviders and jaxRSInInterceptors lists definitions -->    
    <bean id="baseJaxRSServer"
        abstract="true"
        lazy-init="false"
        class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.JAXRSServerFactoryBeanDefinitionParser.SpringJAXRSServerFactoryBean"
        init-method="create"
        p:address="${http.server}/"
        p:providers-ref="jaxRSProviders"
        p:inInterceptors-ref="jaxRSInInterceptors" />
</beans>
```

All of them have a similar specific `Spring` config as well:

```
<beans>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/app/common-rest.xml" />
    <!-- For brevity I left out app1ServiceBeans list definition -->    
    <bean id="app1JaxRSServer"
        parent="baseJaxRSServer"
        p:serviceBeans-ref="app1ServiceBeans" />
</beans>
```

**The problem is**, that when I now deploy the first app it seems quite ok, but every other app bindings are basically not seen at all. It seems that despite all apps have separete `Spring` contexts and separate `CXF` servers and separate `CXF` buses, they still somehow get confused and each of them gets assigned a single `org.apache.cxf.transport.Destination` - the one from the first bundle. Does anyone know how is that possible?

CXF: 2.6.2, Spring: 3.1.4, Karaf: 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

If you're running inside Karaf, I'd suggest first installing the cxf feature and after that just register your cxf endpoints via blueprint, like it's done with Apache Camel. Cause to my knowledge CXF does register one "master" servlet at the cxf context, from where all webservices are accessible. 
At this point you don't need any war. Besides that you didn't show the manifest entry regarding the Web-ContextPath, this is needed for the web container to differ between the servable contextes, so if all of them do have the same context, the first one wins!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm aware of the "master" servlet that this version of `CXF` has. However I'm migrating from `CXF 2.4.2` and used `WARs` and Spring Web contexts, so moving to the solution you suggest, which is correct, would require far too many changes in my application as for one step. Therefore I'm determined to keep `WARs` that, although not explicitly stated, each have different `Web-ContextPath` value. I was able to find a solution that I will post a separete answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was a problem with [`DestinationRegistry`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.6.x/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/DestinationRegistry.html). By default `CXF` registers a single [`DestinationFactory`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.6.x/org/apache/cxf/transport/DestinationFactory.html) that uses a single instance of [`DestinationRegistry`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.6.x/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/DestinationRegistry.html). That's why each [`Server`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.6.x/org/apache/cxf/endpoint/Server.html) was assigned to a single [`Destination`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.6.x/org/apache/cxf/transport/Destination.html), beacuse all of them are mapped to `/` for each servlet, as the `address` field value defines.

The solution that worked for me was to add a separate destination registry per `WAR` bundle. So my `common-rest.xml` now looks like this:

```
<beans>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

    <bean id="httpDestinationRegistry"
        class="org.apache.cxf.transport.http.DestinationRegistryImpl" />

    <!-- For brevity I left out jaxRSProviders and jaxRSInInterceptors lists definitions -->    
    <bean id="baseJaxRSServer"
        abstract="true"
        lazy-init="false"
        class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.JAXRSServerFactoryBeanDefinitionParser.SpringJAXRSServerFactoryBean"
        init-method="create"
        p:address="${http.server}/"
        p:providers-ref="jaxRSProviders"
        p:inInterceptors-ref="jaxRSInInterceptors" />
</beans>
```

The above configuration combined with [`SpringBeanLocator`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.6.x/org/apache/cxf/bus/spring/SpringBeanLocator.html) used by [`SpringBus`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.6.x/org/apache/cxf/bus/spring/SpringBus.html) as a [`ConfiguredBeanLocator`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.6.x/org/apache/cxf/configuration/ConfiguredBeanLocator.html) results in a separate, Spring managed instance of HTTP [`DestinationRegistry`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.6.x/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/DestinationRegistry.html) per each WAR bundle, that in turn allows aproper configuration of the CXF server in each bundle and results in properly finctioning application.

Comment: Any chance you point me in the direction of some sample code of this? How do you configure the `SpringBeanLocator` to find the `DestinationRegistryImpl`?